# How to remove Epiphany from my NixOS while keeping the rest of GNOME?

Tags: uninstallation, gnome, nixos, epiphany

I have GNOME installed in my NixOS version 21.05. Epiphany is a GNOME application for web browsing that comes as a default application. I would like to remove it.

How can I remove Epiphany without removing other parts of GNOME?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [NixOS wiki](https://nixos.wiki/wiki/GNOME), the following snippet can be added to remove GNOME applications **in general**:

```
environment.gnome.excludePackages = [ pkgs.gnome.cheese pkgs.gnome-photos pkgs.gnome.gnome-music pkgs.gnome.gnome-terminal pkgs.gnome.gedit pkgs.epiphany pkgs.evince pkgs.gnome.gnome-characters pkgs.gnome.totem pkgs.gnome.tali pkgs.gnome.iagno pkgs.gnome.hitori pkgs.gnome.atomix pkgs.gnome-tour ];
```

In order to remove **only** Epiphany, the following line must be added to the `configuration.nix` file:

```
environment.gnome.excludePackages = [  pkgs.epiphany ];
```

It worked as expected for me.